# r for loop to assing every file in a list to an individual corpus

Tags: r, for-loop

I whant to resume a lot of similar commands into a for loop.

```
q001<-Corpus(VectorSource(read.table("./q001.txt",encoding="latin1")))
q001<-Corpus(VectorSource(read.table("./q001.txt",encoding="latin1")))
....
q150<-Corpus(VectorSource(read.table("./q150.txt",encoding="latin1")))
```

I have limited computational resources that´s why I want to build separate corpus, clean and make tdm on each of them and later merge all the final tdm into a single tdm matrix

I build the following loop

```
for(i in bNames){
  filepath <- paste("./Sample/", i,".txt", sep="")
  assign(i, Corpus(VectorSource(read.table(filepath,encoding="latin1")))
}
```

Where bNames is a list of files to be read as individual corpus

And gets an error:

```
Error: unexpected '}' in:
"  assign(i, Corpus(VectorSource(read.table(filepath,encoding="latin1")))
}"
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a parenthesis at the end of `assign`

`assign(i, Corpus(VectorSource(read.table(filepath,encoding="latin1"))))`